# I get an error about not finding a matching constructor but the signatures match

Tags: groovy

```
class SharedWorld {
   def db = Db(sql)

   def help = Help(db)
}

class Db {
   Sql sql

   Db(def sql) {
      this.sql = sql
   }
}

class Help {
   Help(){}
   Db db

   Help(Db db) {
      this.db = db
   }
}
```

I have this structure and for some reason when I compile my groovy I get an error that it can't find a matching constructor for Help(Db). Any ideas why? The signature obviously matches

Comment: Your class definitions look bad. Why are enclosing brackets after class name ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few issues with your code.

First, class declarations don't take parameters or need parentheses immediately after the class name.  Try making a constructor for SharedWorld inside the curly braces.  In addition, you need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate classes (although there is a `@Newify` annotation to support the syntax you're using).  Example:

```
class SharedWorld {
    def db
    def help
    SharedWorld(sql) {
        db = new Db(sql)
        help = new Help(db)
    }
}
```